# Spring MongoDB Criteria To Check Inside A List Or Map

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-mongodb

How can I check if a **String** is inside:

```
Set<String> obAccountIDs = new HashSet<String>();
```

in my **User** model?

Is the **in** Criteria method the right approach to use?

[Spring Mongo Query Doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/1.0.0.M5/reference/html/#mongo.query)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or better to use the [$nin](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Criteria.html#nin%28java.util.Collection%29) operator equivalent:

```
Criteria.where("obAccountIDs").nin(IDs);
```

Also noting that [$not](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/not/#op._S_not) is a "field specific" operator that is actually only applying to the operator expression and producing the negative. You would not be able to use that "across documents". So `$nin` is the better action in both cases, apart from requiring less typing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.

```
Criteria.where("obAccountIDs").not().in(IDs);
```